# The feasibility of the electrochemical cell.

Tags: electrochemistry

This is the question extracted from my country high school level' exam. 
So it asks to discuss the feasibility of the electrochemical cell to carry out electrolysis of an aqueous solution of sodium chloride at standard condition.

Al(s)/Al(aq)//Cu(aq)/Cu

My question is how I should start to answer this question?

Comment: Electrode potentials , electrolytic cell and Google will get you started .

Comment: What are the reactions required for electrolysis? What are the possible reactions given the solutions and the electrodes? What are the potentials of the various combinations? Start writing these out and you should see patterns emerging.